# How to find swift version in a programmical way?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to find answer for this question: given **1,000,000** Xcode projects, is there a way to find out what's the swift version, 2.3 or 3.0?

(I definitely know how to check version of **1** project. What I am looking for is a programmical way to check many projects.)

Then I believe the answer to this question might be helpful: How does Xcode identify swift code version?

Is there a file, like JSON, stores all the information but hidden from the users? How can I find this file?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which version of Swift you're running in the `project.pbxproj` file. To check this file out, open up your project's directory, right click your `xcodeproj` file, click "Show Package Contents" and you should see the `pbxproj` file which contains configuration data for your app.

Within this file look for the `XCBuildConfiguration` section and there should be a variable in there for debug and release build settings called `SWIFT_VERSION`. Whatever value is listed there is the version of Swift being used. For instance if the value says `3.0` you can manually change it to `2.3` and reopen the project and it will compile Swift 2.3.

Comment: It looks like reasonable place to store this value but I can’t find SWIFT_VERSION field.

Comment: I too can't find the SWIFT_VERSION field. Can you please tell me how to create a .swift-version file ?